# How to get a money / currency value in an Alexa skill intend?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

How to get a money / currency value in an intend?

I am really surprised that there is no build in slot type for money and/or currency values... The goal is to create an intend that add some money value to an invoice (skill is linked to a web service).

"Add {value} dollar to invoice"

My first try was to configure {value} as AMAZON.Number and to type "Add 5.43 dollar to invoice". This send the following to my web service

```
value": "?"
```

The result for "Add 5 doller to invoice" was just the same. Ok, it seems that AMAZON.Number can only handle written numbers, so "Add five dollar to invoice worked". This is fine because outside the dev environment users will speak the command instead of writing it.

However, what about cent values? What about different currencies?

I added two slots to the intent:

```
"slots": [                        
    {
        "name": "intValue",
        "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",                               
    },{
        "name": "decimalValue",
        "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",       
    }
]
```

But how to define the utterances? Of course I could simple define

```
Add {intValue} dollar {decimalValue} cents to invoice"
```

But this would not be very flexible. It should be possible to use...

- Dollar value only: "5 dollar"
- Cents value only: "23 cents"
- Dollar value + cents value: "5 dollar 23 cents"
- With or without currency: "5 dollar 23 cents", "5 dollar 23", "5 23", etc
- Different currencies: "5 dollar 23 cents", "5 pounds 23 pence", etc.
- No value in the first utterances ("Create new invoice entry") and Alexa asks back for the value

To solve the first five points I did the following:

- Define a custom slot type "Currency" with values "Dollar, Euro,
  Pound, etc."
- Define a custom slot type "Cent" with values "Cent, Pences, Pennies, Rappen, etc."
- Added the following utterances to the intent:

Config:

```
{
    "name": "AddInvoiceValue",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "intValue",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
            "name": "decimalValue",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
            "name": "currency",
            "type": "Currency"
        },
        {
            "name": "cents",
            "type": "Cent"
        }
    ],
    "samples": [
        "Add {decimalValue} {cents} to invoice",
        "Add {intValue} {decimalValue} to invoice",
        "Add {intValue} {currency} {decimalValue} to invoice",
        "Add {intValue} {currency} to invoice"
    ]
}
```

**Problems:**

- If one says "Add 500 17 to invoice" this detected as 517 and not as 500.17 (as definded by {decimalValue} {cents}). This is not a big deal but still not optimal
- "2 dollar 18 cent" is detected as "2 dollar 18 thousand". This problem occurs with different speakers and cannot be solved with very precise pronunciation...
- In German the number one is translated to "eins". However "one dollar four cent" would be translated to "ein dollar vier cent" which would be "a dollar four cent" instead of "one dollar". Nobody would say "eins dollar...". Of course "ein" or "a" are not valid numbers and thus "ein dollar vier cent" is detected as "intValue = ?" and "decimalValue = 4" resulting in "$0,14"

**The biggest Problem:**

How to create a dialog where the user says "Create new invoice entry" and Alexa asks back "How much should be added?".

Creating a dialog is only available if a slot is required, but none of the used slots is required. It should be possible to add intValue only or decimal value only...

**So how to solve this?**

Comment: Hello, did you solve this issue? If you did it, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Dialog](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/dialog-management) feature might be helpful here and in my opinion there is required slot in your Intent - the amount. So then you can use Developer Console to define questions, that Alexa should ask.

Instead of using a built in Dialog mechanism, you can create your own - with some state management (you can use a session storage to persist the state between user's answers). So when Alexa says "How much should be added?" there should be a state set to "WAITING_FOR_AMOUNT", then intent for receiving decimal with some logic inside - when there is a "WAITING_FOR_AMOUNT" state, do something etc.